# MVC build - edit a connectionString file depending on build configuration (VS2012)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, visual-studio-2012, connection-string

When I deploy my MVC site to our test server it will be connecting to a different database and therefore requires different **connection string**.

Usually this can be changed using transforms of the *Web.config*, but unfortunately I'm using a NopCommerce solution where the connectionstring is determined in a text file: **App_Data/Settings.txt**

So, does anyone have any ideas as to how I could alter a line of this Settings.txt file *depending on the build configuration e.g. "Debug" or "TeamCityDebug"?*

I thought about build events (see below) but they occur for all build configurations and not just "Debug" for example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can write a console application to process your Setting.txt
invoke your console application in your pre-build event

> replace.exe "servera" "serverb" "....\Settings.txt"    --for example

in your console application code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(args[3],FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
    string content = sr.ReadToEnd();            
    content = content.Replace(args[0], args[1]);
    fs.Position = 0;
    sw.Write(content);            
}
```

Comment: Ah cool - thanks.  I've also just found the macro to pad out my pseudo code in the pre-build event to find out which build config is being used: 
**`$(ConfigurationName)`**

Comment: Although, thinking about the console application a bit more,  I may need to write a post-build event to revert the file?  Otherwise the next build would have to know if "servera" or "serverb" were last used in order to find and replace it...

Comment: Maybe multiple versions of the file: `SettingsDebug.txt`, `SettingsRelease.txt` etc. and then a console application to copy and rename the correct one to just `Settings.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the suggestions, but I ended up creating multiple `"<something>settings.txt"` files and then using a simple post-build event (command line action) to copy the desired one to into the correct directory and with the required name of `"Settings.txt"`.  The application picks up this files and uses the connectionStrings within it.

I added the following to the post-build events:

```
if $(ConfigurationName) == TeamCityDebug copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)App_Data\TeamCitySettings.txt" 
                                                 "$(ProjectDir)App_Data\Settings.txt"

if $(ConfigurationName) == Release copy /Y "$(ProjectDir)App_Data\LocalSettings.txt"  
                                           "$(ProjectDir)\App_Data\Settings.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
#if DEBUG
    //Load connection from debug file
#else
    //Load connection from release file
#endif
```

Not sure about if you could use custom build configurations like TeamCityDebug but you can give it a try...